# Error while starting thrift server for kerberos enabled hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, kerberos, thrift

i have enabled kerberos on the HDP cluster and trying to connect to Hiveserver2 using python, But getting some error with thrift server .

Tried starting the thrift but getting error as below.Please hlep.

backtrace:

```
     hdp296m1:~ # hbase thrift start
2017-01-20 02:06:43,953 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: HBase 1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258
2017-01-20 02:06:43,955 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: Source code repository file:///grid/0/jenkins/workspace/HDP-build-suse11sp3/bigtop/build/hbase/rpm/BUILD/hbase-1.1.2.2.4.2.0 revision=Unknown
2017-01-20 02:06:43,955 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: Compiled by jenkins on Sun Apr 24 16:30:34 UTC 2016
2017-01-20 02:06:43,955 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: From source with checksum 4f661ee4f9f148ce7bfcad5b0d667c27
2017-01-20 02:06:44,677 INFO  [main] thrift.ThriftServerRunner: Using default thrift server type
2017-01-20 02:06:44,677 INFO  [main] thrift.ThriftServerRunner: Using thrift server type threadpool
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Running in secure mode, but config doesn't have a keytab
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.login(SecurityUtil.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.login(User.java:386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.login(User.java:253)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider.login(UserProvider.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner.<init>(ThriftServerRunner.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer.doMain(ThriftServer.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer.main(ThriftServer.java:232)
```

Hbase config:

[hbase config properties for kerberos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFJPO.png)

Comment: If you navigate to the `/etc/security/keytabs` folder on the server that HBase is running, can you see the hbase.service.keytab file?

Comment: Yes keytab file was present on all nodes.  `    # cmdall ls -lrt /etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab
    #Issuing command to 5 nodes
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 hbase hadoop 508 Nov 29 14:22 /etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 hbase hadoop 508 Nov 29 14:22 /etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 hbase hadoop 508 Nov 29 14:22 /etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 hbase hadoop 508 Nov 29 14:22 /etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 hbase hadoop 508 Nov 29 14:22 /etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab
`

Comment: Actually, reading the log file it seems that it's failing when the "user" is trying to log in. Do you have a principal or keytab associated with the script (or user running the script)? Depending on where you're running the Python script from, you may need a keytab to authenticate with the Kerberos realm.

Comment: My actual problem was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738526/connecting-to-kerberized-hadoop-cluster-using-python-module-impyla?noredirect=1#comment70672327_41738526i and i was trying to start the thrift server by logging into the master node as root itself and tried starting the thrift server as above and getting error.